# Simplemodal multiple dialogs

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using the jquery simplemodal plugin, but i'm not sure that with this plugin is possible open a simplemodal dialog from another simplemodal dialog. Someone knows is it possible?

Thanks,

Lucio

Answer (score 3):

SimpleModal only allows one modal open at a time. You can swap the content or close then re-open a new modal.

Here's an example of how to the latter: http://jsbin.com/aqavo3/

Click "Edit using JS Bin" to view the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your example code work fine! Moreover, my specific problem  is more complex and I need to roll back to modal A from modal B with ALL data previously inserted in modal A. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the SimpleModal Login WordPress plugin. I use one modal to swap out content for 3 different views (login, register, password reset). https://github.com/ericmmartin/simplemodal-login/

Answer (score 1):

I have, recently, found out that, unfortunately, variables in javascript are, actually, global.

So, with that in mind, simply save the contents of the div and re-apply it back if necessary.

currentContent = $('#div').html();
...
...
...
...
...
$('#div').html(currentContent);

That works! I do it myself in one of my applications (websites).